# Implementing a Carousel with Bottom Tab Functionality in React: How is it done on aicarousels.com?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I was trying to replicate some online projects. I stumbled upon this website https://www.aicarousels.com/editor. I was wondering how has been the editing area implemented, Especially the carousel and the bottom setting tab that opens up every time you slide. Can anyone help me in understanding this. I am using react to make my project.

I initially used react carousels but it had some issues as it couldn't center align the last slide when it was set to infinite: 'false'. Regardless I was not able to figure out bottom tab functionality.
Can anyone help me with its architecture and implementation.